# Flickr API for location based images

Tags: ios, iphone, latitude-longitude, flickr

I want to get images of cities when city name is entered in search field in iOS. I am using flickr API but whenever I enter any longitude and latitude values, I only get returned an empty array. What should I do. I am using this URL:

http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.geo.photosForLocation&api_key=e3d577010e5979a2ad2a22714abd901e&lat=40.6700&lon=73.9400&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&auth_token=72157638668602974-e1a3a3aa1e6d3dd8&api_sig=a0233b016c863b1662aeb21a664c351a

Please tell me what should I do. any help appreciated

Comment: Are the photos from the user? Or you want some sort of explore the city photos function.

Comment: i want to use any images uploded from anyone that should be famous image of that city

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that you are seeking too precise a match on your lat-long.  Use the [`&accuracy` parameter](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.geo.photosForLocation.html) to specify a less precise match.  (The default value of 16 specifies a very precise match.)  Flickr suggests a value of 11 to match at the city level, so add

```
&accuracy=11
```

to your URL.

**Update**

I have not had any luck retrieving images with flickr.photos.geo.photosForLocation, but I have retrieved images by lat-long with [flickr.photos.search](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html).  Note this comment in the documentation:

> Geo queries require some sort of limiting agent in order to prevent
>   the database from crying. This is basically like the check against
>   "parameterless searches" for queries without a geo component.
>
> A tag, for instance, is considered a limiting agent as are user
>   defined min_date_taken and min_date_upload parameters — If no limiting
>   factor is passed we return only photos added in the last 12 hours
>   (though we may extend the limit in the future).

Also remember that longitudes of places in the Western Hemisphere are specified as negative numbers.

Comment: i did it but i think there is ~ sign before adding accuracy 11

Comment: I believe the `~` is just a shorthand for "approximately."  That said, I tried a couple of calls with the API Explorer; I get a good status return, but I did not receive any photos.  It's possible that this part of the Flickr API is temporarily down, or perhaps just broken.

Comment: hi, did you ever found a good solution for this issue? Will appreciate the info :)