# How can I get geotagged photos for all users using flickr api?

Tags: flickr, geotagging

I have tried using the [flickr.photos.geo.photosForLocation](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.geo.photosForLocation) method. However that only gets photos for the authorised user, I need one for all users!

Basically I want to create [this](https://www.flickr.com/map/) (or panaoramio) but using flickrs photos.

Is this possible? If so how can I get this data from the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [flickr.photos.search](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html) to search by lat-long.  There are some quirks, which I call out in [my answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586697/flickr-api-for-location-based-images).